# Alguien me puede decir por que no muestra el resultado de la especialidad?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, revisión-de-código, condiciones

En la primera imagen cuando ejecuto el codigo me muestra la salida para el NIVEL en este caso SUPERIOR, pero no me muestra la ESPECIALIDAD, pero si comento el codigo para el NIVEL si me muestra la especialidad, a que se debe esto me pueden ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Esto se debe a que su variable nivel toma otro valor en este caso SUPERIOR, por eso al intentar ingresar al IF donde eliges tu especialidad nunca entra ya que su nivel a cambiado. 1.- su variable nivel es: `i` 2.- su variable nivel es: `SUPERIOR` por ende nunca entrara en el codigo para asignar especialidad. Lo que te recomiendo hacer es utilizar otra variable para asignar los valores de tus niveles.

Comment: muchísimas gracias lo tomare en cuenta eso de las variables

Comment: pero te diste cuenta de tu error?? , si la respuesta te resulta util marcala como respuesta positiva con la flecha hacia arriba, que esta en el costado superior izquierdo de la respuesta saludos.

Comment: cuando tenga puntos de reputación lo pondre como util